# gitlab webhooks:no data post and error occurred

Tags: gitlab, webhooks

I write a asp.net web `API` to get data that gitlab webhooks posts.but that, I can not receive data from gitlab webhooks . What's more,when I click button 'Test Hook' at `gitlab`,there is a error

> Hook execution failed:{"Message"=>"An error has occurred.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUFbI.png)"}.I don't know how to solve this problem!
>   I need any help!